# Cordova Windows Phone 8.1 app lifecycle events don't fire?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

Does anyone have a workaround/suggestion for getting Cordova 4.x or 5.0.0 to fire the 'pause' and 'resume' app lifecycle events for Windows Phone 8.1?

To repro this:

- start a new VS2013 project using the default Tools for Apache Cordova template.
- set breakpoints at the end of the default onPause and onResume functions in index.js
- run with the emulator targeting Windows Phone Universal

  - if you don't see the javascript console, you'll need to quit and run from the CordovaApp silverlight VS solution found in (myApp)\bld\Debug\platforms\windows
- tap the windows back arrow
- long press the windows back arrow, choose your blank app

EXPECTED: when either the windows back button or windows button are tapped, the the app should stop at the breakpoint. Likewise the app should stop at the breakpoint when the app is resumed

ACTUAL RESULTS: neither breakpoint is triggered.

COMMENT: I ran into this because we have some interval timers that are set up when the app launches (and on onResume) and are shutdown onPause. These interval timers don't get turned off, indicating that the onPause function was not executed. Of course, this leads to the undesirable "flattening of the battery" but worse is that if there were pending operations like web connections they can't be cancelled when the app is leaving the foreground. Subsequent relaunches may or may not crash as a consequence and once the app gets into a crash-on-launch mode, it cannot be relaunched until it's deleted and reinstalled.

Comment: Can you share a simpler repro of your application. I have tried this with a simple blank Cordova application and I am not able to reproduce the problem. Thanks of using our tools!

Comment: Thank you Subhag -- the default TACo template app is about as simple as I can get. A blank cordova app stops at the onPause and onResume breakpoints for you? NOTE: When I trigger a lifecycle event, it'll stop at the onPause breakpoint, but not from just pressing the windows back key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While an app is being debugged, Windows will not suspend it. This behavior is documented at : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/06/17/suspend-and-resume-in-winrt.aspx

If all threads were frozen, the debugger would not be able to interact with the application once suspended. As you mentioned, you can trigger lifecycle events to simulate suspending/resuming. Hope this helps, thanks!